# Can't use InputParameter["Target"] in crm 2011 plugin using Send message

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a plugin that is registered against email entity using the send message.

`context.InputParameters["Target"]` is not found.

I found some old 4.0 code that use InputParameters["EmailId"].

I am confused as to how I can obtain this informaiton. I haven been scouring the internet an dcan find no list of these parameters or how to figure this problem out. Every msdn site talks about what input parameters are but only lists Target as an example. Pleas ehelp me understand this. Direct Question: Where can i find a list of these parrameters to make sur ei am doing this right.?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The inputParameters are different depending on which platform 'message' you are subscribing to.  Can you provide a larger code sample?

Comment: I am trying to get a list for all the messages. The old code worked but i want to know how i could have gotten that information if i never found old ocde lying around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The go-to source for input and output parameters in CRM 4 was Patrick Verbeeten's blog.](http://www.patrickverbeeten.com/Blog/2008/01/25/CRM-40-Plug-in-message-input-parameters)  I would assume it is still pretty relevant for CRM 2011.  It appears the information can also be extracted from the metadata as he has a tool for [CRM 2011](http://www.patrickverbeeten.com/CRM-Applications/Dynamics-CRM-Developers-Tool-2011).

If you accept this answer, go Thank Pat for his effort :)